# Installer script for OSX, python + node

Tags: python, macos, bash, installation

I'm writing what is a relatively small desktop application, but I'm using several technologies/languages and not sure the best way to create a installer script.

I have a python script which uses tornado and scapy (which also requires pcapy), and have a kernel extension that needs to be installed.

This python script is executed and works in conjunction with a node-webkit (nw) app I'm writing.  Any suggestions on the easiest way to ensure all of the dependencies are met, and properly installed without the user having to touch the command line?  Using python setuptools or pyinstaller?  Package it together with nw?  Use OS X packagemaker?  Writing a bash script?  Should I distribute these dependancies with my actual app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using python2 or python3? Dependencies for scapy differ.

Comment: I am maintaining python3 version of scapy, and there could be differences, but in general it sounds either as a binary wheel (https://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or pyinstaller package. It depends more on the potential user - admins would prefer wheel, end users - pyinstaller package. I would start from wheel and go to pyinstaller if necessary.